# k nearest neighbor : Error using - Matrix dimensions must agree [MATLAB]?

Tags: matlab, matrix, knn

l tried to implement the k-nearest neighbor classifier for image classification after executing the code below l got this error :

> Error using  - 
>   Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in Sevennn_classifier (line 19)
>           tmp = test_point-train_point(1:end - 1, :);

consider that  :

```
size(test_point) = 1       10000
size(train-point)=  1       60000
```

here is my code :

```
% load training set and testing set
clear all;
train_set = loadMNISTImages('/home/anelmad/Desktop/TER/mnist_ml2/MNIST_digit_recognition-master/load_data/train-images.idx3-ubyte');
train_label = loadMNISTLabels('/home/anelmad/Desktop/TER/mnist_ml2/MNIST_digit_recognition-master/load_data/train-labels.idx1-ubyte');
test_set = loadMNISTImages('/home/anelmad/Desktop/TER/mnist_ml2/MNIST_digit_recognition-master/load_data/t10k-images.idx3-ubyte');
test_label = loadMNISTLabels('/home/anelmad/Desktop/TER/mnist_ml2/MNIST_digit_recognition-master/load_data/t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte');

% cliassify the testing set 
train_scale = size(train_set);
test_scale = size(test_set);
test_classify_label = zeros(test_scale(1),1);
tic;
for i=1:test_scale(1)
    test_point = test_set(i,:);
    dist = zeros(train_scale(1),1);
    for j=1:train_scale(1)
        % calculate the distance between test point i and train point j
        train_point = train_set(j, :);
        tmp = test_point-train_point;
    dist(j) = sqrt(sum(tmp.*tmp));
    end

    % find the 5-nearest neighbor 
    dist_tmp = sort(dist);
    num = zeros(10, 1);
    for k=1:7
       idx = find(dist==dist_tmp(k));
       num(train_label(idx)+1) = num(train_label(idx)+1)+1;
    end

    % classification
    maxIdx = 0;
    maxNum = -1;
    for k=1:10
      if(num(k)>maxNum)
         maxIdx = k;
         maxNum = num(k);
      end
    end 
    test_classify_label(i) = maxIdx-1;
end
t1 = toc;
% calculate accuracy
num_correct = sum(test_label==test_classify_label);
accuracy = num_correct / test_scale(1);
save -mat 7nn_time.mat t1
save -mat 7nn_accuracy.mat accuracy
```

Comment: So line 19 is `tmp = test_point-train_point;`, right? What are the dimensions of `test_point` and `train_point`. Obviously the dimensions must agree for the subtraction. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you have 1x10000 and 1x60000 how do you think this should work out?

Comment: so have l to set  trainpoint to  trainpoint=(1:size(test_point)) ?

Comment: Did you forget to replace the line in the copied code? The sizes must match.